# Entity: Return set of records that are in a subset of an array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have three tables: Student, Course, and StudentCourse.  StudentCourse is just a junction table (aka side table, link table, etc) that contains a unique Id for the row as well as a Student Id and Course Id.

I have an array of integers that represent courses, so an input could simply be 1,2,3. (This will come from a GET request for a REST API, but the source doesn't really matter).

Given an array of integers, I want to return all students that are associated with all of the course Id's that are in the array.  HOWEVER, I still want to return those students who might not have an passed in course Id, because they don't even have that many associations.

To outline this, suppose we have the following:

[image]

Student1 has courses 1,2

Student2 has courses 2,3,4

I pass in an array containing 1,2,3.  Even though Student1 does not have course Id 3, they should still be returned (their course list is a SUBSET of what I passed in).

Comment: ***HOWEVER, I still want to return those students who might not have an passed in course Id*** - So technically you need it to return all students - either the input students you have to all in the db.

Comment: BTW, post what code you have tried here. I now may understand what you mean a bit. What you want may be ***get all students joining in at least 1 course in the courses specified via a list of ids***.

Comment: Not quite, I basically want all Students that are a Subset of the array of id's that I passed in.

Comment: if so the second comment of mine above is what you want, you should post some code you have now (at least something about your model), I may help.

Comment: It's not, since it's not "at least one" but ALL ids, except those ones that the Student isn't even associated with. Using my example above, if I passed in 1, nothing would be returned because 2 was not passed in. 1,2,3 would return Student1 because 1 and 2 were passed in, but we ignore 3

Comment: ah yes, so what about your model? this could be done with some concrete query, so some model should be provided.

Comment: The example is identical to the model, the table is the result of using code first in entity. So it'd be StudentCourse with the shown fields.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `Student` entity and `Course` entity. If you design your models correctly, `Student` should expose `Courses` and `Course` should expose `Students`.

The query can be like this (using `Contains`):

```
//the input courseIDs
var courseIDs = new [] { 1,2,3 };
var students = Students.Where(e => e.Courses.All(x => 
                                     courseIDs.Contains(x.ID)).ToList();
```

Here is another query using `Except`:

```
var students = Students.Where(e => e.Courses.Select(x => x.ID)
                                    .Except(courseIDs).Count() == 0)
                                    .ToList();
```